# Как сверстать фоновое изображение с нижней границей в виде неравномерной волны?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Имеется фоновое изображение, которое имеет нижнюю границу в виде неравномерной волны, внутри которого содержится изображение человека, которое должно не вылезать за пределы фонового изображения. Если вставлять фоновое изображение в формате svg, даже при использовании свойства overflow: hidden; изображение человека внизу не обрезается нужным образом. Логичным кажется использование свойства clip-path, но так как нижняя граница неравномерная, то с помощью онлайн-генераторов добиться абсолютно идентичного эффекта очень сложно. Есть ли онлайн-генераторы, которые могут преобразовать код с svg-изображения в clip-path? Или какими ещё свойствами возможно сделать подобное фоновое изображение?

Comment: https://www.shapedivider.app/ попробуй это должно тебе помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Волну я нарисовал в [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/release/inkscape-1.0/) - перо и обводим по контуру всю фигуру и сохраняем в файл с расширением svg с любым именем

Чувака я не нашёл такого же и потому в yandex написал так "бизнесмен png без фона"

Дальше работа ручная:  берём весь path и помещаем его между тегами defs и используем его несколько раз

1. как фон документа
2. как маска для изображения

Если не достаточно умений писать svg в ручную то есть подробный мануал:  [svg документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG)

Ну и собственно пример того что я объяснял

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 292.63 127.08" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
 <path id="path" d="m225.82 126.95c-32.277-4.8755-55.441-5.0214-84.667-2.2167-10.833 1.0449-13.065 1.1974-20.108 1.3742-11.813 0.29644-19.841-0.5398-32.147-3.3484-17.103-3.9035-34.676-5.8911-55.695-6.2994-9.4271-0.18312-23.735-0.0148-29.832 0.35089l-3.3734 0.20242v-117.02h292.63l-0.1334 117.55-1.0583 0.37096c-13.599 4.7666-32.071 8.266-47.228 8.9467-5.3707 0.24122-14.807 0.28379-18.389 0.083z" />
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" />
      <use href="#path" x="0" fill="#fff" />
    </mask>
</defs>
  
<use href="#path" x="0" fill="#6580FD" />
  <image href="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/african-american-businessman-png-11.png" width="100" height="100" x="100" y="25" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```